# CMake Undefined reference when creating executables

Tags: cmake

I am new to CMake and I am trying to get my project compiling. The project creates a few static libraries and a few executables.

Below is the example of the file structure that I have.

PROJECT

- SRC

  1. subProject_1
     .cpp (all source files) and CMakeLists.txt 1 for this folder (creating a static library)
  2. subproject_2
     .cpp (all source files) and CMakeLists.txt 2 for this folder (creating a static library)
  3. subproject_3
     .cpp (all source files) and CMakeLists.txt 3 for this folder (creating the executable)
- Include

  1. subProject_1
     .h (all the header files)
  2. subProject_2
     .h (all the header files)
  3. subProject_3
     .h (all the header files)
- build/linux

  1. CMakeLists.txt (Main CMakelist file)

Main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
Project(ort)
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -g -Wall -pThread")

#set the source and header directories location
set(ORT_HEADER_DIRECTORY "../../include") #include folder structure explained above
set(ORT_SOURCE_DIRECTORY "../../src")
set(ORT_BINARY_DIRECTORY "../../lib")  # lib folder to contain all the libraries

set (CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR ".")

#Include the library packages
include_directories("/usr/include/wx-2.8")
include_directories("/usr/local/cuda/include") and so on


#set the names of all the projects (for creating the libraries)
SET(PROJECT_NAMES "log" "data" "cc")

foreach(PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAMES})
     # Create the cmake related files in the out folder so that the libraries can be
     # copied to the lib folder
     add_subdirectory( "{ORT_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/out/${PROJECT_NAME}"

endforeach(PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAMES})

#set the names of all the projects (for creating the libraries)
SET(EXECUATALE_PROJECTS "metadata" )

foreach(EXECUATALE_PROJECT ${EXECUATALE_PROJECTS})
     # Create the cmake related files in the out folder so that the libraries can be
     # copied to the lib folder
     add_subdirectory( "{ORT_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/${EXECUATALE_PROJECT}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/out/${EXECUATALE_PROJECT}"

endforeach(EXECUATALE_PROJECT ${EXECUATALE_PROJECTS})
```

CMakeLists.txt file for log directory (the same logic I have used for cc and data projects)

```
include_directories(${ORT_HEADER_DIRECTORY})
SET(LOG_SOURCE a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp)
ADD_LIBRARY(log_d ${LOG_SOURCE})
target_link)libraries(log_d cc_d data_d)
```

metadata CMakeLists.txt file  (creating the executable project)

```
FIND_PACKAGE(wxWidgets)
IF(wxWidgets_FOUND)
        INCLUDE(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
ENDIF(wxWidgets_FOUND)

Include_Directories(${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${ORT_HEADER_DIRECTORY})
include_directories("/usr/ort/lib/unixODBC/include")

SET(META_SOURCE meta.cpp data.cpp)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(meta_d ${META_SOURCE })
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(meta_d log_d data_d)
```

When I just make the project, without the creation of the executables, static files are being generated. But, when I make the whole project (i.e. with the inclusion of the subProject_3 directory) I get undefined reference to `a::String` which is a function in a.cpp.

Note: All the 3 projects are dependent on each other. For example, in a.cpp, I have `#include "b.h"` and in b.cpp I have `#include "a2.h"`.

So, I have few questions:

a) How do I resolve the undefined reference issue? Once I have generated the libraries for project 1 and 2, how do I link these to the executable?

b) Should I provide or add any dependencies when I am creating the static libraries? Is this the right way of creating the static libraries (as the projects are inter dependent)?
i.e. `target_link_libraries(project1 project2 ...)` in project 1 and `target_link_libraries(project2 project1 ...)` in project 2.

c) Every project needs to be compiled with its own compilation setting. Can you please let me know how can I specify the same for every individual project?

ERROR DETAILS:

Liking CXX executable metadata_d
../log/liblog_d.a: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I also get the undefined reference error
/home...../metadata/data.cpp 172: undefined reference to xmlSerahNs
and so on.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

> How do I resolve the undefined reference issue ? Since, I have generating the libraries for project 1 and 2, how do I link these to the executable.

Just use [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) again, this time in subProject3's CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(subProject3 subProject2 subProject1)
```

---

> Is this the right way of creating the static libraries (as the projects are inter dependent)

Yes.  From the docs for `target_link_libraries`:

> The library dependency graph is normally acyclic (a DAG), but in the
>   case of mutually-dependent STATIC libraries CMake allows the graph to
>   contain cycles (strongly connected components). When another target
>   links to one of the libraries CMake repeats the entire connected
>   component. For example, the code
>
> ```
> add_library(A STATIC a.c)
> add_library(B STATIC b.c)
> target_link_libraries(A B)
> target_link_libraries(B A)
> add_executable(main main.c)
> target_link_libraries(main A)
> ```
>
> links 'main' to 'A B A B'. (While one repetition is usually
>   sufficient, pathological object file and symbol arrangements can
>   require more. One may handle such cases by manually repeating the
>   component in the last target_link_libraries call. However, if two
>   archives are really so interdependent they should probably be combined
>   into a single archive.)

---

> Every project needs to be compiled with there own compilation setting. Can you please let me know how can I specify the same for every individual project?

In the top-level CMakeLists.txt, before adding the subdirectories, you can set all the flags you need there.  (see [`add_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_definitions) and [`Properties on Targets`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#section_PropertiesonTargets) for example)  They will be adopted by all the subprojects unless specifically changed for a subproject.

Comment: Hi Fraser. Thanks for your response. W.r.t target_link_libraries I did something like this:

target_link_libraries(subProject3 subProject1 subProject2)

But, I am still getting an error
libsubProject1.a: file not recognized: File truncated.

Comment: In Addition, when I just tried with target_link_libraries(subProject3 subProject_1 subProject_2) I am getting the below error:

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsubProject_1

Comment: @Pintu Are you sure you're using the right names throughout?  Your example code can't be an exact copy of what you're running since there are a few errors in it.  Even your comment above indicates inconsistent naming.  It looks like your folders are maybe called e.g. subProject_1 (with underscore) and the targets defined inside maybe `subProject1` (without underscore).  If that's the case, you need to specify `subProject1 subProject2` in the `target_link_libraries` command, not `subProject_1 subProject_2`.

Comment: Yes, I am using the correct names. I have edited the question description to add more code details. I have provided you the one that I am currently using. Please let me knwo why I am getting the error.

Comment: I figured out why I am getting the undefined reference. I forgot to include few static libraries and that caused the problem. Thanks a lot fraser. Totally appreciate your help.